# Reading Multi Dimentional array only print 1st Charcter of Child Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, woocommerce, dashboard

I just want to show "Order Type" in my result but I am getting first character of my 2nd Dimensional array.
It also shows the warning of "**Illegal string offset 'Order Type'** "

My code

```
<?php
$data=Array ( 

                "Order Type" => Array ( 'delivery' ),
                "When" => Array (  'Later' ),
                "Time" => Array (  '12:30' ),
                "Date" => Array (  'Sat, 17-Jan' ) 
            );

foreach($data as $innerArray)
{
    foreach($innerArray as $result)
        {
            echo $result["Order Type"];
        }
}
```

Comment: May be I'm missing something, but to show order type all you need is $data["Order Type"][0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 <?php
    $data=Array (
        "Order Type" => Array ( 'delivery' ),
        "When" => Array (  'Later' ),
        "Time" => Array (  '12:30' ),
        "Date" => Array (  'Sat, 17-Jan' )
    );

    foreach($data as $index => $innerArray)
    {
        if($index == "Order Type")
         echo $innerArray[0];
    }
```

or you can directly write

```
 if(!empty($data["Order Type"][0]))
        echo $data["Order Type"][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write `echo $data['Order Type']` you will receive the `array('delivery')` so you can use `$data['Order Type'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
foreach($data as $innerArray)
{
    foreach($innerArray as $result)
        {
            echo $result['delivery'];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($data as $key => $innerArray)
    {
        if($key == "Order Type") {
            // if order type array will hold always single index value then use it
            echo $innerArray[0];
            // if it will hold also multiple indexes value then use
            foreach( $innerArray as $innerArrayVal) {
                echo $innerArrayVal;
            }
        }
    }
```